# How change the CKEditor text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ckeditor, bbcode

I have a textarea with CKEditor (bbCode Plugin).

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="conteudo" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
```

This is my CKEditor instance:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'textarea#editor1' ).ckeditor();
} );
```

I'm making a `JSON` request that takes a value and I want this value to be modified in this `textarea`, I tried with `jQuery` but not worked !
Below is my attempt:

```
video_id = "lLi1Lx2xTKI";

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
    description = data.data.description;
    // Attempt here
    $("#editor1").html(description);
});
```

**UPDATE**

I tried using '.val()' and not worked!

Comment: tried $( 'textarea#editor1' ).val(description) ?

Comment: Yes, @Wilmer. Not worked.

Comment: No reason to use jQuery... `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData("<p>HELLO</p>");`

Comment: You need to include the jquery adapter file if you want to use val() check http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter

Comment: Here's the [jQuery adapter guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery) for CKEditor 4.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't simply add text to the CKEDITOR via jQuery, instead go with [**api**](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData) given by CKEDITOR

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(data.data.description);
```

Here your code looks like

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){   
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(data.data.description); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/43/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing the description directly into the text area, try the CKEditor setData method.  You can find a description of it here:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-popup

also be sure that your description variable does have a value, I'd use a temporary `alert(description);` for this but you may be able to do it with a javascript debugger also.