# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined using Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to filter words(ants,words) using ckeditor.This works fine with normal textarea. http://jsfiddle.net/fqthJ/22/ .Now I am trying it with ckeditor http://jsfiddle.net/s47M3/35/ but I get the following error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined using Ckeditor`

If you check on the console ,I get the above error only once I type the filtered words(ants and words) otherwise no error comes.

Please help

Comment: Change `$(this).val().match(regAry[index])` to `value.match(regAry[index])`; `this` isn't what you think it is

Comment: thnx ian,ur answer also worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I have been trying to solve a same type of question yesterday that you have posted.

The problem is [you can't use jQuery long with CKEDITOR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105783/1671639) and therefore you faced the error.

***FIX:***

```
alert("The following word/words  "+
          CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData().match(regAry[index])+" is banned");
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/s47M3/41/)

If you're interested with [**`jQuery Adaptor`**](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery) of CKEditor, then you can go with your own.

Comment: plz help with this questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126352/key-events-not-working-for-multiple-ckeditors

Answer (score 1):

In the second fiddle, try putting a `debugger;` line just before `alert('the following words...` and then open up your browsers developer console before running it again. You'll notice that the `$(this)` is a CKEditor specific dom [element](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element) that looks like an iFrame so `.val()` will probably fail, because it looks for strings. I don't know enough about CKEditor to figure out how to get editor content out of it, but know that it is *html formatted* if you browse around in the `CKEditor.dom.element`, so it will contain html elements in addition to ordinary text etc.

Comment: thnx for the suggestion