# Key events not working for multiple ckeditors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/s47M3/41/)
Here a filter word is alerted to the user when he types it on the `ckeditor`.In my example the filtered words  `are ants and words`.So if you type these words it will alert the user.

**html**

```
<input type="textarea" id="editor1"/>
<div id="dest"></div>
```

**js**

```
var filter = ['ants', 'words'], // our list of words
    regAry = new Array(), // we'll create one regex per word for testing
    alertedWords = new Array(), // keep track of how many words there were at the last alert, for each word
    reg = new RegExp("(/s" + filter.join("|") + "/s)", "g"); // one regex to rule them all!

for(var f in filter) { // setup...
    regAry[f] = new RegExp(filter[f], "g"); // one regex per word for testing
    alertedWords[f] = 0; // no alerts yet, so 0 for each word
}
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
//var value = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
//alert(value);

 editor.on('contentDom', function() {
 editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {

for(var index in regAry) { // loop over our list of words
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
       var test = value.match(regAry[index]); // test how many times this word appears
       if( test && test.length > alertedWords[index] ) // if it appears more than the last time we alerted...
       {
           alert("The following word/words  "+ CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData().match(regAry[index])+" is banned"); // do an alert!
       }
        alertedWords[index] = (test ? test.length : 0); // update the word count for this word
    } // keep looping     

 });
 });
```

Now my problem arises if I have 2 or more ckeditors like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/s47M3/45/)
It doesnt seem to work.Although the editors appear but alerts dont appear.

**html**

```
<input type="textarea" id="editor1"/>
<input type="textarea" id="editor2"/>
<div id="dest"></div>
```

**js**

```
var filter = ['ants', 'words'], // our list of words
    regAry = new Array(), // we'll create one regex per word for testing
    alertedWords = new Array(), // keep track of how many words there were at the last alert, for each word
    reg = new RegExp("(/s" + filter.join("|") + "/s)", "g"); // one regex to rule them all!

for(var f in filter) { // setup...
    regAry[f] = new RegExp(filter[f], "g"); // one regex per word for testing
    alertedWords[f] = 0; // no alerts yet, so 0 for each word
}

for(var i=1;i<3;i++){
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor'+i );
//var value = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
//alert(value);

 editor.on('contentDom', function() {
 editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {

for(var index in regAry) { // loop over our list of words
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'+i].getData();
       var test = value.match(regAry[index]); // test how many times this word appears
       if( test && test.length > alertedWords[index] ) // if it appears more than the last time we alerted...
       {
           alert("The following word/words  "+ CKEDITOR.instances['editor'+i].getData().match(regAry[index])+" is banned"); // do an alert!
       }
        alertedWords[index] = (test ? test.length : 0); // update the word count for this word
    } // keep looping     

 });
 });
}
```

What to do?

Comment: input type="textarea" ??? that's not a valid type for an input element so the browser will handle it just type="text". You sould use the textarea element instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to value of `i`. When the events (`contentDom`,`keyup`) are triggered,  the `i` is `3`. So the listeners are trying to work with `CKEDITOR.instance("editor3")`,which does not exist at all. The solution will be, to add listeners by separate function, which accepts `i` as an argument:

```
for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
   addListeners(i);
}
function addListeners(i){
   //body of for loop
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s47M3/47/)

Answer (score 1):

Dont do it with `for` loop but do it with jquery `each`, like:

```
$( 'input[type=textarea]').each( function(indx) {

  var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( $(this).attr('id') );

  .....
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s47M3/46/)**

Comment: thnx for the answer but I need to use the for loop.the reason being I am getting the limit of the ckeditors from the database,so i need to use for